# .htaccess redirect peaple friendly url with parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I try to make the URL of my site a litle more readable, but I have trouble doing this.

Her are samples of the URL it Looks like now:

```
http://example.com/
http://example.com/index.php
http://example.com/index.php?page=home
http://example.com/index.php?page=profile&uid=483ec3a0-7e0f-32e6-f357-ac9311204246
```

They have to look like:

```
http://example.com/
http://example.com/home/
http://example.com/profile/483ec3a0-7e0f-32e6-f357-ac9311204246/
```

Here is the Content of my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from /view.php?id=1 to /view/id/1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?page=([^\s&]+)&uid=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/? [L,R=301]

# internal forward from /view/id/1 to /view.php?id=1
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&uid=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It rewrites correct an URL like `http://example.com/index.php?page=profile&uid=483ec3a0-7e0f-32e6-f357-ac9311204246` -> `http://example.com/profile/483ec3a0-7e0f-32e6-f357-ac9311204246/` but i get everytime an 404 error. If i try to call `http://example.com/` or `http://example.com/home/` i get an 500 error.

What is my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another redirect rule for no parameters and you need to add some conditions to your internal forwarding rules so that `/index.php` doesn't get matched:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from /view.php?id=1 to /view/id/1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?page=([^\s&]+)&uid=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php($|\ ) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R=301]

# internal forward from /view/id/1 to /view.php?id=1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&uid=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: OK, thank you. I get no 500 errors but i still get the 404 Errors.

Comment: @JohannLöwen If you comment out the first three redirect rules, does going to `http://example.com/index.php?page=profile&uid=483ec3a0-7e0f-32e6-f357-ac9311204246` give you a 404?

Comment: yes, if I comment out the first three rules so it works fine.

Comment: Thank you guys, you are great. The Solution was the sum of your both answers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're hitting problem of infinite looping causing 500. It is due to the reason that last 2 routing rules aren't skipping files and directories.

**Insert this rule just above `# internal forward` line:**

```
# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: Thank you guys, you are great. The Solution was the sum of your both answers.